# Optimising a MySQL Query that takes ~30 seconds to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query to get the total notes input by each users between a date range. This is the query I am running:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
    COUNT(notes.user_id) AS "Number of Notes"

FROM csu_users

JOIN notes      ON notes.user_id    = csu_users.user_id

WHERE notes.timestamp BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"
AND notes.system = 0

GROUP BY csu_users.user_id
```

Some notes about my setup:

- The query takes between 30 and 35 seconds to run, which is too long for our system
- This is an InnoDB table
- The `notes` table is about 1GB, with ~3,000,000 rows
- I'm deliberately using `SQL_NO_CACHE` to ensure an accurate benchmark

The output of `EXPLAIN SELECT` is as follows (I've tried my best to format it):

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys             key       key_len ref                           rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      csu_users   index   user_id                   user_id   5       NULL                          1     Using index
1   SIMPLE      notes       ref     user_id,timestamp,system  user_id   4       REFSYS_DEV.csu_users.user_id  152   Using where
```

I have the following indexes applied:

**`notes`**

- Primary Key - `id`
- `item_id`
- `user_id`
- `timestamp` *(note: this is actually a `DATETIME`. The name is just misleading, sorry!)*
- `system`

**`csu_users`**

- Primary Key - `id`
- `user_id`

**Any ideas how I can speed this up? Thank you!**

Comment: Why not to show the SQL query without  g_users and g_people if it doesn't matter? Are our lives to easy? :)

Comment: Sorry, good point! I'll edit it now to simplify things.

Comment: try using **WITH(NOLOCK)**

Comment: @Luv can you clarify where/how? This is an InnoDB table.

Comment: Not related to your question, but using between with your timestamps might be giving you wrong answers.  It's a lot safer to go with >= date1 and < the day after date2.

Comment: You should try a different table as basis. So try 'SELECT ... FROM notes JOIN csu_users ...' because notes is the big one. Furhter more do you realy need a normal JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN for example?

Comment: @JaMaBing Unfortunately swapping the primary table made no difference to the speed.

Comment: @JackW-H To effectively change the order of a JOIN, you have to use STRAIGHT_JOIN instead. Otherwise the optimizer will decide the order of the JOIN and you changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, by converting your timestamp to a string representation, you're loosing all advantages of the index on that column. try using timestamp values in your comparison

Comment: Just to complete the answer, the solution is to just omit DATE_FORMAT and use notes.timestamp directly.

Comment: I have tried this in the past, but ran it again. The `WHERE` clause now reads: `WHERE notes.timestamp BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"` and it still takes 30s to run :-(

Comment: P.S. This might be a bit misleading, I know it's named `timestamp`, but it's not actually stored as a `TIMESTAMP` - it's stored as a `DATETIME` (I inherited the table, sorry)

Comment: Same stuff, you need to keep it to the original data type , so you have to create 2 datetime values for end date and start date, then compare notes.timestamp to those variables, without converting notes.timestamp to a string, which date_format does. You should only use date_format to display a user-friendly date, not in the conditions, especially with such a big table.

Comment: Like this? `WHERE notes.timestamp BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("2013-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") AND STR_TO_DATE("2013-01-31", "%Y-%m-%d")` - same result, 30 second query...

Answer (score 1):

Is the `csu_users` table necessary?  If the relationship is 1-1 and the user id is always present, then you can run this query instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(notes.user_id) AS "Number of Notes"
FROM notes 
WHERE notes.timestamp BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2013-01-31" AND notes.system = 0
GROUP BY notes.user_id
```

Even if that is not the case, you can do the join *after* the aggregation and filtering, because all the conditions are on `notes`:

```
select "Number of Notes"
from (SELECT notes.user_id, COUNT(notes.user_id) AS "Number of Notes"
      FROM notes 
      WHERE notes.timestamp BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2013-01-31" AND notes.system = 0
      GROUP BY notes.user_id
     ) n join
     csu_users cu
     on n.user_id = cu.user_id
```